# AES-CTR in BouncyCastle with string key, without IV or salt

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

Our team is encrypting data using a javascript snippet. My problem is I'm supposed to parse them back in my Java code. I am having troubles identifying parts of the algorithm. The code says it's CTR but doesn't provide a 256 key, an IV or a salt, as it only takes a simple string and goes from there. A key looks like `"aasdg-safg-gwerg-wrgwrg"`

javascript example

```
var encr = Aes.Ctr.encrypt('big secret', 'aasdg-safg-gwerg-wrgwrg', 256);
```

then that encr string is sent and received on the java side to be decrypted

```
String decr = ?????? // THIS IS WHAT I'M AFTER
```

HINT: This webpage does the algorithm correctly for strings https://www.pidder.de/pidcrypt/?page=demo_aes-ctr

A copypaste of the script can found here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html

```
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  AES Counter-mode implementation in JavaScript       (c) Chris Veness 2005-2014 / MIT Licence  */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

/**
 * Encrypt a text using AES encryption in Counter mode of operation.
 *
 * Unicode multi-byte character safe
 *
 * @param   {string} plaintext - Source text to be encrypted.
 * @param   {string} password - The password to use to generate a key.
 * @param   {number} nBits - Number of bits to be used in the key; 128 / 192 / 256.
 * @returns {string} Encrypted text.
 *
 * @example
 *   var encr = Aes.Ctr.encrypt('big secret', 'pāşšŵōřđ', 256); // encr: 'lwGl66VVwVObKIr6of8HVqJr'
 */
Aes.Ctr.encrypt = function(plaintext, password, nBits) {
    var blockSize = 16;  // block size fixed at 16 bytes / 128 bits (Nb=4) for AES
    if (!(nBits==128 || nBits==192 || nBits==256)) return ''; // standard allows 128/192/256 bit keys
    plaintext = String(plaintext).utf8Encode();
    password = String(password).utf8Encode();

    // use AES itself to encrypt password to get cipher key (using plain password as source for key
    // expansion) - gives us well encrypted key (though hashed key might be preferred for prod'n use)
    var nBytes = nBits/8;  // no bytes in key (16/24/32)
    var pwBytes = new Array(nBytes);
    for (var i=0; i<nBytes; i++) {  // use 1st 16/24/32 chars of password for key
        pwBytes[i] = isNaN(password.charCodeAt(i)) ? 0 : password.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var key = Aes.cipher(pwBytes, Aes.keyExpansion(pwBytes)); // gives us 16-byte key
    key = key.concat(key.slice(0, nBytes-16));  // expand key to 16/24/32 bytes long

    // initialise 1st 8 bytes of counter block with nonce (NIST SP800-38A §B.2): [0-1] = millisec,
    // [2-3] = random, [4-7] = seconds, together giving full sub-millisec uniqueness up to Feb 2106
    var counterBlock = new Array(blockSize);

    var nonce = (new Date()).getTime();  // timestamp: milliseconds since 1-Jan-1970
    var nonceMs = nonce%1000;
    var nonceSec = Math.floor(nonce/1000);
    var nonceRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*0xffff);
    // for debugging: nonce = nonceMs = nonceSec = nonceRnd = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) counterBlock[i]   = (nonceMs  >>> i*8) & 0xff;
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) counterBlock[i+2] = (nonceRnd >>> i*8) & 0xff;
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) counterBlock[i+4] = (nonceSec >>> i*8) & 0xff;

    // and convert it to a string to go on the front of the ciphertext
    var ctrTxt = '';
    for (var i=0; i<8; i++) ctrTxt += String.fromCharCode(counterBlock[i]);

    // generate key schedule - an expansion of the key into distinct Key Rounds for each round
    var keySchedule = Aes.keyExpansion(key);

    var blockCount = Math.ceil(plaintext.length/blockSize);
    var ciphertxt = new Array(blockCount);  // ciphertext as array of strings

    for (var b=0; b<blockCount; b++) {
        // set counter (block #) in last 8 bytes of counter block (leaving nonce in 1st 8 bytes)
        // done in two stages for 32-bit ops: using two words allows us to go past 2^32 blocks (68GB)
        for (var c=0; c<4; c++) counterBlock[15-c] = (b >>> c*8) & 0xff;
        for (var c=0; c<4; c++) counterBlock[15-c-4] = (b/0x100000000 >>> c*8);

        var cipherCntr = Aes.cipher(counterBlock, keySchedule);  // -- encrypt counter block --

        // block size is reduced on final block
        var blockLength = b<blockCount-1 ? blockSize : (plaintext.length-1)%blockSize+1;
        var cipherChar = new Array(blockLength);

        for (var i=0; i<blockLength; i++) {  // -- xor plaintext with ciphered counter char-by-char --
            cipherChar[i] = cipherCntr[i] ^ plaintext.charCodeAt(b*blockSize+i);
            cipherChar[i] = String.fromCharCode(cipherChar[i]);
        }
        ciphertxt[b] = cipherChar.join('');
    }

    // use Array.join() for better performance than repeated string appends
    var ciphertext = ctrTxt + ciphertxt.join('');
    ciphertext = ciphertext.base64Encode();

    return ciphertext;
};


/**
 * Decrypt a text encrypted by AES in counter mode of operation
 *
 * @param   {string} ciphertext - Source text to be encrypted.
 * @param   {string} password - Password to use to generate a key.
 * @param   {number} nBits - Number of bits to be used in the key; 128 / 192 / 256.
 * @returns {string} Decrypted text
 *
 * @example
 *   var decr = Aes.Ctr.decrypt('lwGl66VVwVObKIr6of8HVqJr', 'pāşšŵōřđ', 256); // decr: 'big secret'
 */
Aes.Ctr.decrypt = function(ciphertext, password, nBits) {
    var blockSize = 16;  // block size fixed at 16 bytes / 128 bits (Nb=4) for AES
    if (!(nBits==128 || nBits==192 || nBits==256)) return ''; // standard allows 128/192/256 bit keys
    ciphertext = String(ciphertext).base64Decode();
    password = String(password).utf8Encode();

    // use AES to encrypt password (mirroring encrypt routine)
    var nBytes = nBits/8;  // no bytes in key
    var pwBytes = new Array(nBytes);
    for (var i=0; i<nBytes; i++) {
        pwBytes[i] = isNaN(password.charCodeAt(i)) ? 0 : password.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var key = Aes.cipher(pwBytes, Aes.keyExpansion(pwBytes));
    key = key.concat(key.slice(0, nBytes-16));  // expand key to 16/24/32 bytes long

    // recover nonce from 1st 8 bytes of ciphertext
    var counterBlock = new Array(8);
    var ctrTxt = ciphertext.slice(0, 8);
    for (var i=0; i<8; i++) counterBlock[i] = ctrTxt.charCodeAt(i);

    // generate key schedule
    var keySchedule = Aes.keyExpansion(key);

    // separate ciphertext into blocks (skipping past initial 8 bytes)
    var nBlocks = Math.ceil((ciphertext.length-8) / blockSize);
    var ct = new Array(nBlocks);
    for (var b=0; b<nBlocks; b++) ct[b] = ciphertext.slice(8+b*blockSize, 8+b*blockSize+blockSize);
    ciphertext = ct;  // ciphertext is now array of block-length strings

    // plaintext will get generated block-by-block into array of block-length strings
    var plaintxt = new Array(ciphertext.length);

    for (var b=0; b<nBlocks; b++) {
        // set counter (block #) in last 8 bytes of counter block (leaving nonce in 1st 8 bytes)
        for (var c=0; c<4; c++) counterBlock[15-c] = ((b) >>> c*8) & 0xff;
        for (var c=0; c<4; c++) counterBlock[15-c-4] = (((b+1)/0x100000000-1) >>> c*8) & 0xff;

        var cipherCntr = Aes.cipher(counterBlock, keySchedule);  // encrypt counter block

        var plaintxtByte = new Array(ciphertext[b].length);
        for (var i=0; i<ciphertext[b].length; i++) {
            // -- xor plaintxt with ciphered counter byte-by-byte --
            plaintxtByte[i] = cipherCntr[i] ^ ciphertext[b].charCodeAt(i);
            plaintxtByte[i] = String.fromCharCode(plaintxtByte[i]);
        }
        plaintxt[b] = plaintxtByte.join('');
    }

    // join array of blocks into single plaintext string
    var plaintext = plaintxt.join('');
    plaintext = plaintext.utf8Decode();  // decode from UTF8 back to Unicode multi-byte chars

    return plaintext;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "translate this algorithm"? Do you want to be able to encrypt something in one and decrypt in another and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, a correct test would encrypt in one and decrypt on the other, and viceversa.

Comment: You have to provide the relevant code for both JavaScript and Java in the question itself and some examples of your trial and error. Why are you using CBC mode in the Java code if the title says CTR mode?

Comment: @ArtjomB. nothing I've tried worked because any KeyFactory requires IV or salt, and I have none and none can be deduced from the scripts.

Comment: Ok, that's somewhat better, because now we see what you're talking about which makes this a give me teh codez question. I reduced the code to the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the comments in the Javascript?  It is well commented, and the comments are there for a reason.

`use AES itself to encrypt password to get cipher key`

Can you code that in Java?  Then:

`initialise 1st 8 bytes of counter block with nonce (NIST SP800-38A §B.2)`

Can you code that in Java?  CTR mode uses a nonce instead of an IV.

Given the key and the nonce you should be able to code AES-CTR decryption.  If you hit problems, then check that your output at every stage matches the Javascript output byte-for-byte.  If you still can't find the problem, then ask again here, showing us your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the internals of the Bouncy Castle implementation, but I used to code these things for fun before the days of Java, and there are some key points you can check to pinpoint where the problem is. Unfortunately, there probably isn't a simple one line answer to the question.

While the core of the algorithm is more than likely OK (this is what the test vectors tell you), my guess is that you are not getting what you want because the password handling, and how it is wrapped into the key bytes is quite sloppy.

It is often the case that key handling is unclear, because anything will do **until** you come to do interoperability testing. The test vectors don't give you any help with this, because the vectors used to set up the test (key, IV input) and the results are expressed as hex values.

In the implementation above, the password bytes are encoded using UTF8, then the UTF8 bytes are put into the pwBytes up to the required key length, truncating them to the maximum expected. If you don't put in enough bytes, then the array is left with the default value.

Now, I'm no JavaScript expert, but to me there seems a lot left to chance in that. What exactly is the result of the UTF8 encoding IN HEX? How are multibyte characters handled IN HEX? What exactly is the value of the uninitialised pwBytes entries IN HEX?

So, first step in understanding your problem: dump out the hex bytes of the pwBytes array with a known key. And compare this to the equivalent key bytes in the Bouncy Castle implementation. If this turns out the same, they you'll have to look further because the problem is somewhere else.

Just one thing: If the pidder implementation is working OK, why not use that? It's GPL, and the implementation pleases me much more. If interoperability works with pidder, it means that someone has gone through your pain for you already.

Comment: If you read the documentation, this is what pidder uses internally. I'm unable to reproduce it in Java due to the homebrew key generation. I've tried asking in crypto.stackoverflow and not even them can write a correct java solution for it.

Answer (score -1):

I work for some project on AES Encryption in Java, with BouncyCastle and SunJCE as providers. Please anyone correct me if i'm wrong, but there is no method that accept passkey as String. However, you could do this:

```
byte[] iv="someString".getBytes();
SecretKeySpec secretKey=new SecretKeySpec(yourPasswordAsString.getBytes(), "AES");
AlgorithmParameterSpec spec=new IvParameterSpec(iv);
Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, spec);
byte[] encrypted=cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
```

`
Remeber that if you want to get the result as String you need to convert it as Base64, you can use ApacheCommonsCodec. You will have something like:

```
String encryptedString=new String(new Base64().encode(encrypted);
```

Remember also that you need to re-convert the encrypted text as non-Base64. You can do so: `byte[] notBase64=new Base64().decode(encryptedString)`
Remember also taht yoour passkey need to be 16 (or 32 charachter if you have JCE installed or BouncyCastle).
Hope it helps.

Comment: What is "someString", that script only takes yourPasswordAsString and that's all the info you have.

Comment: Probably it is not the better implementation, but in one of my program "someString" (which is the Initial Value) is yourPasswordAsString, so the String that user inserts into your program. You can also have IV generated with a Random(), but for me it is not good, because you need to have the same IV in encryption and in decryption, so a random value it is not a good choice. But remember that the IV must be 128 bits. Hope it can help you better now @MLProgrammer-CiM

Comment: Maybe, I could post all of my code for encryption/decryption as String, if it is necessary.

Comment: Nicola:  Note that somehow you need to communicate both the IV and the AES key to the receiving party.  It is not good practice to use the same IV for multiple messages, so a randomly generated IV is typically used.

Comment: @user3745362 yes it is true, it depends on your requirements, for mine I use IV from password, I know that a random one it is more secure. But for mine it must be necessary to work only on password.

Comment: The IV has not been communicated to me, that's the issue here.

Comment: Using the same IV, as user3745362 already sayed it is not a good practice. But you can do, if you want (I recommend no). You can generate the IV from the password (for example you can hash it and then take only 128 bits). Or, but I don't known how I can write it, you can try to use AES with ECB mode. This mode doesn't use any kind of IV, but it more unsecure. Maybe you can search for this. @MLProgrammer-CiM

Comment: But again, this is not what I'm after. Someone is encoding values using that script, I need to decode them on the same fashion. There is no IV and there won't be one. Putting a random, my password or anything will not make the algorithm work because the encryption was not using one.